# validation issue with zend checkbox

Tags: zend-framework

everyone, I have create a zend form have a checkbox for license agreement. I want to show an error message when a user submit the form with out checking the agreement check box.

Thanks 
Anurodh

Comment: What is the question here? Stack Overflow isn't a free mind-reading help line.

Answer (score 8):

There is a bug in zend_framework with the required checkbox. But you can do something like this.

```
$this->addElement(
      'checkbox', 'checbkox_name', array(
            'required' => true,
            'uncheckedValue' => null
        )
    );
```

edit for readability

```
$acceptAggrement = new Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox('accept_aggrement');
$acceptAggrement->setLabel("Accept Aggrement :");
$acceptAggrement->setUncheckedValue(null);
$acceptAggrement->setRequired(true);
```

Comment: how can we do the above same with
 $acceptAggrement = new Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox('accept_aggrement');
           $acceptAggrement->setLabel("Accept Aggrement :")

Comment: $acceptAggrement = new Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox('accept_aggrement'); $acceptAggrement->setLabel("Accept Aggrement :"); $acceptAggrement->setUncheckedValue(null); $checkElement->setRequired(true);

Comment: You want to also add the check for the $formObject->isValid() .